# Visual Studio Code доступ по ssh через другую машину

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, visual-studio-code

Есть есть локальная сеть, в ней одна машина видима извне. На другой - сурсы программ (Ubuntu). Хочется использовать visual studio code для написания кода, но не смог разобраться, как пробросить тоннель через другую машину (аля ssh -L ...) через vs code. Есть ли решение?

Comment: `sshfs` пробовал?

Comment: Лучше будет настроить git или hg через ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо don Rumata, я использовал sshfs через ssh tunell и открыл примонтированную директорию в vs code. Для windows на локале я использовал [billziss-gh порт sshfs](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win)

Comment: Все таки рекомендую посмотреть в сторону моего решения. Довольно удобно выходит. Особенно радует что при "копировать относительный путь" слеши правильные :)

Answer (score 0):

Я использую [remote плагины](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview), а именно [remote ssh](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). Хост - винда 7 + cygwin, исходники на astra linux.